# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll when trying to make simple insertion into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to C# and I have encountered error when trying to create a new user from my C# project and insert into the database. I kept encountering the following error when running the project:

> Exception thrown: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

but can't seem to find which part of the code went wrong. I have tried googling for similar solutions but have not been of help.

The following is my database and table from SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

The following is the connection string in my web.config file to connect to the SQL Server database:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=XXX-091220MI02\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=serviceportal;Integrated Security=true"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The following is the my code in Visual Studio when trying to insert into database:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon);

           if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           {
               conn.Open();
           }

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (@user, @pass)", conn);
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Textbox 1 Text: " + TextBox1.Text.Trim());
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Textbox 2 Text: " + TextBox2.Text.Trim());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox2.Text.Trim());

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           conn.Close();

           Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Redirecting to Login Page ...');</script>");
           Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
           Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.StackTrace +"');</script>");
     }
}
```

Comment: Please, add message of exception - without it it's too generic question

Comment: What is the value of `ex.ToString()`?

Comment: I'd suggest `INSERT [user]` rather than `INSERT INTO user`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: To find the exact location of the problem, it is useful to set "Break when Thrown " in the Exception Settings

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Understood, I have made the necessary amendments to the question.

Comment: You should dispose your connection and command with `using` block. And yiou don't need to check if the connection is closed, you just created it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this -

```
insert into [dbo].[user] (username, password) values (@user, @pass)
```

Comment: Why should he do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15[link]

Answer (score 0):

Please change the insert statement as 'user' is keywords in database.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[user] (COLUMNS) VALUES();
```

Please ensure your connection string is correct.

Answer (score 0):

USER is a reserved word for sqlserver; if you call your table User you'll have to quote its name when using it. Consider renaming your table to Users, or quoting it ( `insert into [user]` ). One nice thing about giving tables plural names is they seldom collide with keywords, (though "should table names be singular or plural is a bit of a holy war" ..)

Bad:

[image]

Good:

[image]

Note: the fact that those images show a create table statement is immaterial; using "user" without quoting it doesn't work in an insert in the same way it doesn't work in a create

---

Some other points:

- consider avoiding AddWithValue on SQLServer - https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/ - I don't care so much about insert statements but it causes problems with select statements
- give your textboxes etc proper names. It takes a few seconds to rename a control, do not stick with the default "TextBox1" name- by the time you've added a hundred controls your code will be meaningless and hard to follow
- do not store passwords in plain text. Read up on what hashing and salting is, and always always always salt-hash your passwords. Code like this coupled up with human nature of reusing passwords is the reason why password lists and rainbow tables exist and why one hack leads to many. Once someone has hacked your site and scraped all the user's carefully chosen mega secure 16 character random char passwords into a list they can just try them anywhere else to get a win. You can't turn round and say "well it's their fault for reusing a password" - there are two faults, but storing the password in plain text is the bigger one (because it's easier to fix than human nature). If you don't want to store user data securely, hand the problem of authentication/authorisation off to someone else, like auth0 or Microsoft azure AD
- if you're learning db interaction, using Dapper or EF might be the better way to go; this is really low level code you're writing- it's a lot of lines/effort for very little overall action. In EF all your code would have looked something like:

```
    db.Users.Add(new User { Username = userTextbox.Text, Password = passTextBox.Text });
    db.SaveChanges();
```

...and it would have worked, because EF knows how to quote table names